# how to link prebuild so in jni

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have created a header file "abc.h" with declaration

```
int abc();
```

Then, I created a .cpp file "abc.cpp" with definition

```
int abc()
{ 
  return 10;
}
```

Now I created a  library libabc.so from above files.

I have then created a HelloWorld Android project. Then I created a lib folder in jni and put the libabc.so file init.

Now I have created another file "xyz.cpp" in jni folder which wants to use `abc()` function.
 But when I run `ndk-build` command I get this error. 
 `Error: undefined reference to function abc` .

**This is xyz.cpp file.**

```
int getAbcFunction()
{
    int value = abc();
    // return value;
}
```

**Android.mk in jni---> lib folder**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := abc-prebuild
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libabc.so
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Android.mk in jni folder**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := helloworld
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := xyz.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := abc-prebuild
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How  to solve this error.

Comment: run `ndk-build V=1` to see what parameters the compiler is called with, if that doesn't guide you to the right direction, add that information to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include "abc.h"` to the beginning of xyz.cpp

Comment: after including this header file same error is coming

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio, your Makefiles are ignored by default because all the configuration is supposed to be made using the gradle or gradle-experimental plugin.

However native prebuilts aren't supported yet by these, hence you should deactivate the default support and call ndk-build yourself:

```
android.sources{
    main.jni {
        source {
            srcDirs 'src/main/none' //deactivate built-in compilation
        }
    }
    main.jniLibs {
        source {
            srcDir 'src/main/libs' //integrate .so files from src/main/libs
        }
    }
}
```

btw, that isn't totally related to your issue, but you have:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libabc.so
```

That means that you intend to use this prebuilt (armeabi?) for all the architectures the NDK supports (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips, mips64), even if they aren't compatible. You should do

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libabc.so
```

instead and have different versions of your .so file.